# find_packages() does not include main project folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I'm having trouble excluding files in the setup.py file. First I show the project structure.

```
myscript
├── myscript
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── myscript.py
├── README.md
├── LICENSE
└── setup.py
```

The contents of the setup.py file are as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open('README.md') as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(name = 'myscript',
    version = "1.0",
    description = 'Example desc',
    long_description = long_description,
    long_description_content_type = 'text/markdown; charset=UTF-8',
    license = 'MIT',
    author = 'Jalkhov',
    author_email = 'jalkhov@gmail.com',
    packages = find_packages('myscript', exclude=['tests.py']),   
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'myscript=myscript.myscript:main',
        ],
},
)
```

When I run `python setup.py sdist` with the file like this, and install the **.tar.gz** file that it generates for me, it installs correctly, but when I try to run the script from the console, it throws me the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\myscript.exe.main__.py", line 4, in <module>ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myscript'
```

Then I check the `site-packages` folder and the only thing concerning the script I find is the `myscript-1.0.dist-info` folder

But when I modify the package line and leave it like this:

```
packages = ["myscript"],
```

And I install, everything runs fine, but the file I want to exclude has been included in the `site-packages` folder.

It seems that by using the `find_packages` function I don't care about the main folder of the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually have a package at all, so don't use `find_packages`.  Use [`py_modules`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#options) instead, for making a single-file distribution.

Recommend a project layout like this:

```
myscript
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── myscript.py
├── setup.py
└── tests
    └── test_myscript.py
```

And modify `setup.py` like this:

```
setup(
    ...
    py_modules=["myscript"],
)
```

Comment: I'd recommend renaming the directory `tests` to `test`, this way it's automatically picked up to be placed in the _sdist_, while still not installed and not placed in the _bdist_.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `myscript/myscript/__init__.py` file is missing.

> Anyway, `find_packages()` walks the target directory, filtering by inclusion patterns, and finds Python packages (any directory). Packages are only recognized if they include an `__init__.py` file. Finally, exclusion patterns are applied to remove matching packages.

-- [*setuptools* documentation for `find_packages`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages)

Comment: But the second myscript folder is not a package, it is the folder containing the source code and the tests file. I don't really understand the **packages** parameter, it's used to look for packages, that is, folders containing modules, or to point to the source code of the script? in this case the second myscript folder, because as I said, it's not a package.

Comment: @Jalkhov I must have missed this information somehow. If it's not a package but just a module, then use the `py_modules` parameter of `setuptools.setup` function call. See wim's answer.